# Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, foreign-collection

I've checked other concerns like this. Checked if there were duplicates-none, if same data type -yep. relationships- yep. Not using "On Delete Set Null" checked.

I'm still lost how this error came to be

Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

---

-- Table `Apo`.`PurchasingOrder`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Apo`.`PurchasingOrder` (

`PurchaseNo.` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`ModelNo.` INT NULL,

`UnitPrice` INT NULL,

`Product/Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

`Quantity` INT NULL,

`Source` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`PurchaseNo.`),

INDEX `Source` (`Source` ASC),

CONSTRAINT `Supplier_Source`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`PurchaseNo.`)

REFERENCES `Apo`.`Supplier` (`SupplierID`)

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Nothing to fetch

Comment: Is this Microsoft sql? if so you should add that tag

Answer (score 0):

Could you check whether all your PurchaseNo values in Apo.PurchasingOrder are valid values of SupplierID in Apo.Supplier?

Comment: Update: Error was triggered when I changed the table names. Despite changing the column names, it seems ok. 

Now my problem is changing the Table Name w/o causing an error because the original table names had spaces "Purchasing Order" (which is bad practice) :(